# Define X=R\{k} and define ⋆ to be the operation such that x⋆y=(x−k)(y−k)+k. Does this satisfy closure?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, proof-explanation, axioms

Define X=R{k} and define ⋆ to be the operation such that x⋆y=(x−k)(y−k)+k. Check each of the four axioms of a group (closure, associative, identity, inverse). Which of them hold? Is (X,⋆) a group.

It says that X can't contain the number k, thus X would be a group only if x ⋆ y != k. But theres a k in the definition of the operation. does that mean that it automatically isnt closed? if not, why ? because ive found that x ⋆ y = k if and only if x =k or y = k which is impossible in the first case which means it is closed.  also, can an inverse or identity be not in the set by chance ?

Comment: @azif00 Yes i know, but why are we allowed to have k in the definition of the operation when k is not even in the set ?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read your post completely. It seems that your question has already been answered.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said the result of $x\star y$ can only be $k$ if $x=k$ and $y=k$, but since that's not allowed you can conclude that $x\star y = k$ is **impossible**, thus $(X,\star)$ is closed.

To finde the identity element $1_\star$ you have to solve
\begin{align*}
x \overset{!}{= }x \star 1_\star = (x-k)(1_\star-k)+k
\end{align*}
for $1_\star$ which should result in $1_\star = k+1$ (which is not $k$).

In order to find inverse elements you have to solve
\begin{align*}
k+1 = 1_\star \overset{!}{= }x \star x^{-1} = (x-k)(x^{-1}-k)+k
\end{align*}
for $x^{-1}$ which should result in $x^{-1} = \frac{1}{x-k}+k$ (which can never be $k$)

In order to check for associativity you have to check that
\begin{align*}
((x-k)(y-k)+k)(z-k)+k = (x\star y)\star z \overset{!}{=} (x-k)((y-k)(z-k)+k)+k 
\end{align*}
which will turn out to be **not** true.

Comment: Thank you, but you didnt really answer my question. we have k in the definition of our operation ⋆ but k cant be in X. so why are we allowed to use k in the definition of ⋆

Comment: In the definition $x\star y = (x-k)(y-k)+k$ the operations on the right side are in the usual in $(\mathbb{R},+,\cdot)$ and thus $k$ is allowed there. And you analyse how the $\star$-operation behaves when you plug in numbers which are **not** $k$. But there is no reason not to allow $k$ in the definition of $\star$

Comment: @user20194358 If it helps you can think of $\star$ as a function $\star: \mathbb{R}\backslash \{k\}\times \mathbb{R}\backslash \{k\} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Even though $k$ is not allowed as an input in $\star$ it can still be in the definition. In the same way that e.g. the number $2$ is in the definition of the function $f(x) = \frac{1}{x-2}$ but it would not be allowed as an input since that would result in $\frac{1}{0}$

Comment: okok thank you-, this makes perfect sense. and also im pretty sure it is associative . first you do (x⋆y) ⋆ z. then you do x ⋆ (y⋆z) and you will see that they are the same. why wouldnt they be the same, since the right hand side is made up of addition and multiplication which is known to be associative.

Comment: If you do the calculations carefully you will see, that they're actually not the same and that thus $\star$ is not associative